# How can I access the data attribute of an <a> anchor element using JS?

Tags: javascript, attributes, elementor

I'm trying to access a data attribute (data-elementor-lightbox-title)for an  anchor in order to output the titles on mobile. Here's the code I tried to access all of the  anchors on the page.

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('a.dataset.elementorLightboxTitle');
console.log(el);
```

Here's an example of one of the  anchors with the data-elementor-lightbox-title attribute that I'm trying to access:

`<a class="e-gallery-item elementor-gallery-item elementor-animated-content" href="https://julianp2.sg-host.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Literaturwurst-hanging_-Autonomie-Gallery.jpg" data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" data-elementor-lightbox-slideshow="all-19a736f1" data-elementor-lightbox-title="test" data-elementor-lightbox-description="test" style="--item-height:133.333%; --column:1; --items-in-column:0; --percent-height:0%;">`

But this is only returning a node list, which I'm not able to traverse to find the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `data-` attribute of any element using the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) object. Another [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset). Like so

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(a.dataset); // This returns an object of all the data-attributes of the element written in camelCase
```

```html
<a data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" data-elementor-lightbox-slideshow="all-19a736f1" data-elementor-lightbox-title="test" data-elementor-lightbox-description="test">
```

The `data- attribute on the HTML elements is written in lowercase, seperated by hyphens (`-`). Just for the elements to have the same format as other html attributes. For example,` data-elementor-open-lightbox`

But to access the value of that attribute in JS, you have to rewrite the attribute in `camelCase` that is the first letter of the every word except the first is written in uppercase letters while all the rest are written in lowercase.

For example, the HTML `data-attribute` `data-elementor-open-lightbox` will be written as `elementorOpenLightbox` (as you can see the data wasn't written). In JS you could simply run,

```
a.dataset.elementorOpenLightbox // And you'll get yes as the return value
```

Comment: When I try this, it's only returning a DOMStringMap that doesn't contain the attribute. And trying to grab the attribute from the dataset is returning undefined, unfortunately.

Comment: I'll explain better in the answer

Comment: This now works for me with the small edit below. I was able to do this if I added a class to the query selector (otherwise it returns undefined on my site, even though it works fine in the snippet):


`const a = document.querySelector('a.e-gallery-item');
console.log(a.dataset.elementorLightboxTitle) `